# transition is not adding up in img created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i am clicking on a character it should be added in 'Animated-Pokemon' span but with transition but the transition is not being applied

this is my HTML where the image should be created

```
 <div class="Pokemon-Area">
                        <span id="poke1" class="Animated-Pokemon">
                        </span>
                        <img src="../Pokemon-Images/game.png" alt="logo" width="40%" id="logo-Img1">
                    </div>
```

and this is my CSS code

```
.Animated-Pokemon{
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
   left: -30;
   opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.3);
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.5s;
}
.Animated-Pokemon.show{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    
}
.Animated-Pokemon img{
width: 14vw;
}
```

and Js code

```
function handlePokemonClick(pokemonName) {
  const imageName = pokemonName.replace(' ', '_'); 
  const imagePath = `../Animated-Img/${imageName}.gif`;

  const animatedPokemon = document.createElement('img');
  animatedPokemon.src = imagePath;
  animatedPokemon.alt = pokemonName;
animatedPokemon.classList.add('show');


  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    const slot = document.getElementById(`poke${i}`);
    if (slot.children.length === 0) {
      slot.innerHTML = '';
      slot.appendChild(animatedPokemon);
      slot.style.display = 'block';
      break; 
    }
  }
}
```

when the image is created it should add show class applying transition to the image (I have put the opacity in Animated-Pokemon to 1 because with 0 its not showing because theres no transition)
but when i move from one program to chrome i can see the transition but not when its clicked

I tried everything but nothings working it was working when the img was singular Help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you add the show class when you create it. This way there is nothing to transition from. Either you need to add the element before, and adding the Show class later when you want to apply the transition, or you need to add a keyframes animation like this:

```
.Animated-Pokemon{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqc4fgbp/27/)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the `show` class before appending the image to the DOM. This means that the image will be added to the DOM having the class already and no transition will occur. The browser needs to see the state change to apply the transition.

You're also setting the opacity to 1 in the `.Animated-Pokemon` class which is essentially it's final state. The browser won't see any change in the property and therefore no transition occurs.

This is the ideal time to use `requestAnimationFrame` - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is an explanation on how the method works as per MDN docs. You can use `requestAnimationFrame` to ensure the initial state is applied first, and then the class with the final state `show` is added, which tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation before the next redraw.

Here is an updated version of your JS code:

```
function handlePokemonClick(pokemonName) {
  const imageName = pokemonName.replace(' ', '_'); 
  const imagePath = `../Animated-Img/${imageName}.gif`;

  const animatedPokemon = document.createElement('img');
  animatedPokemon.src = imagePath;
  animatedPokemon.alt = pokemonName;

  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    const slot = document.getElementById(`poke${i}`);
    if (slot.children.length === 0) {
      slot.innerHTML = '';
      slot.appendChild(animatedPokemon);
      slot.style.display = 'block';

      // Force a reflow, flushing the CSS changes
      void animatedPokemon.offsetWidth;

      // Use requestAnimationFrame to apply the final class after one frame
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        animatedPokemon.classList.add('show');
      });
      
      break; 
    }
  }
}
```

And in your CSS, set the initial `opacity` to `0` and remove the initial `opacity` and `transform` from `.Animated-Pokemon.show`

```
.animated-pokemon {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.3);
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.5s;
}

.animated-pokemon.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

P.S. - it is best practice for `kebab-case` to be used with CSS and DOM element class names so I have added these in for you. Just change the markup to also match the css class names ;)